# How are multipolar expansion of earth magnetic field computed?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, multipole-expansion, spherical-harmonics, geomagnetism

In the study of the geomagnetic field, an [expansion in spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion#Expansion_in_spherical_harmonics) is used to represent the scalar magnetic potential: the first terms give the dipole approximation, then the quadrupole, etc.

For instance, we can find here ([International Geomagnetic Reference Field](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/international-geomagnetic-reference-field)) reference data for the magnetic field, given as coefficients of a spherical harmonics expansion.

My question is: how are those coefficients calculated?

I was thinking of the Monte Carlo method, but I couldn't find any information on that.

Note that I would also accept answers related to the gravitational field as the question also applies there.

Comment: The paper https://backend.orbit.dtu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/110842635/2015_228.pdf gives the definition of the coefficients in the table (in particular, the formula is normalized using earth radius so that all coefficients are homogeneous to a magnetic field). It doesn't answer my question though.

Answer (score 1):

The IGRF model of Earth's magnetic field is based on measurements from satellite and ground-based magnetometers. These instruments record magnetic field strength and direction at known locations. The magnetic field can be expressed in terms of the scalar magnetic potential, $V$, such that $\mathbf{B} = -\mathbf{\nabla} V$. This potential is given by a spherical harmonic expansion using the IGRF model coefficients.

Time varying coefficients are ultimately fitted to the observations. According to this [article](https://doi.org/10.1186/s40623-020-01288-x) these represent median values for several different candidate models. These would be computed based on a least squares method or some other cost function minimisation technique.

Comment: That's an interesting answer, but I'll leave the question open as I'd like to know precisely the method used to determine the coefficients based on the samples.

Comment: @Weier The best approach to answering that would be to look at the papers describing each of the individual candidate models (referenced in the link above). Details may vary.